# select option depends other option in wordpress admin page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

I have two selections category and type, the type should come depending on the category selection, from the database, here is my code.

HTML

```
    $ps_type_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'ps_type'; ?>

    <form method="post" action="">
     <label>Category :</label><br>
         <select id="category" name="category" 
         class="form-control">
               <?php
         $categories = $wpdb->get_col('SELECT DISTINCT category FROM '.$ps_type_table_name);
                 foreach ($categories as $category){ ?>

               <option value="<?php echo $category; ?>"><?php echo $category; ?></option>
                   <?php
                      }
                      ?>
             </select><br><br>

             <label>Types :</label><br>
            <select id="type" name="type" class="form-control">

           </select><br><br>
   </form>
```

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#category').on('change',function(){
                var category = $(this).val();
                if(category){
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'category-type-select.php',
                        data:'category_name='+category,
                            success:function (html) {
                        $('#type').html(html);
                    }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

PHP

```
 class Get_category_type{
 function __construct()
 {
if (isset($_POST['category_name']) && !empty($_POST['category_name'])) {
    global $wpdb;
    $category = $_POST['category_name'];
    $ps_type_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'ps_type';
    $types = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT type FROM ' . $ps_type_table_name . ' WHERE category=%s', $category));

    foreach ($types as $type) {
        echo '<option value="' . $type . '">' . $type . '</option>';
    }
}
}

}
```

actually, this is a WordPress plugin using oops, please help me to solve this problem, I think the problem is getting PHP file in ajax code, please tell me how to write path in ajax URL to get that class file in WordPress plugin

Comment: is there any error in your browser console

Comment: no, it was not showing any error but it was displaying nothing in select  type section

Comment: i think __construct function will called only when the new object instance if created . so you need to create instance to run the constructor function .

Comment: if I remove class and write it directly then also it's not working, i think i have to path to call PHP file inside WordPress, like:plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)/category-type-select.php, I don't know currect way of writing it

Comment: your current page and category-type-select.php is in same directory or different directory ? @Deekshith Shetty

Comment: it is in same directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for my problem so i posting answer to help some who needed, in WordPress, there is separate hook is there to use ajax function, and this procedure how to use it.

HTML

```
 $ps_type_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'ps_type'; ?>

<form method="post" action="">
 <label>Category :</label><br>
     <select id="category" name="category" 
     class="form-control">

           <?php
           $categories = $wpdb->get_col('SELECT DISTINCT category FROM '.$ps_type_table_name);
             foreach ($categories as $category){ ?>

       <option value="<?php echo $category; ?>"><?php echo $category; ?></option>

               <?php
                  }
                  ?>

         </select><br><br>

         <label>Types :</label><br>
        <select id="type" name="type" class="form-control">

       </select><br><br>
```

PHP code to get second option value by changing the first option

```
 public function get_type_by_category(){
    //echo file_get_contents('php://input'); for testing
    if (isset($_POST['ctgry']) && !empty($_POST['ctgry'])) {
        global $wpdb;
        $result = "";
        $category = $_POST['ctgry'];
        $ps_type_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'ps_type';
        $types = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT type FROM ' . $ps_type_table_name . ' WHERE category=%s', $category));

        foreach ($types as $type) {
            $result .= '<option value="' . $type . '">' . $type . '</option>';
        }
        echo $result;
    }
}
```

Hook this function to wordpress

```
    add_action('wp_ajax_get_type_by_category','get_type_by_category');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_type_by_category','get_type_by_category');
```

Ajax.js

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#category').change(function(){
    var ctgry=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:ajaxurl,
        data:{'action':'get_type_by_category','ctgry':ctgry},
        cache:false,
        success:function (html) {
            $("#type").html(html);
            //alert(html);
        },
        error:function(request,string_error,error){
            alert(string_error);
        }

    });
});
$('#category').change();
});
```

Hook js to WordPress

```
    public function enqueue_scripts(){
 wp_enqueue_script('ps-admin-page-js', plugins_url('js/admin-page.js', dirname(__FILE__)),array('jquery'),'1.1.1',true);
 }
 add_action('wp_footer', 'enqueue_scripts');
```

I found this way to use ajax in WordPress plugin development, and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are replacing the option to select element.You need to have the select element also in the ajax php.

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'category-type-select.php',
    data:{category_name:category},
    success:function (html) {
                            //
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
$result='<select id="type" name="type" class="form-control">';
foreach ($types as $type) {
        $result.= '<option value="' . $type . '">' . $type . '</option>';
    }
$result.='</select>';

echo $result;
```

Comment: no, it's not working, it's a WordPress plugin, I think the problem is in ajax URL section how to call a PHP file in Ajax, inside WordPress

Comment: ok then problem is something else.i updated the answer with ajax data part.just try like that.

Comment: In the console network you can check the url.right click and open it in new tab.Is it showning the data?.

Comment: sorry i did not get u?

Comment: open console and go to network.then change the option in category.you can see the ajax url in the console.right click and open it in new tab

Comment: give the echo to query and run it in database

Comment: how? it is wordpress plugin

Comment: no bro its not helped me, I got an answer, I have posted that answer here

Answer (score 0):

**1st :** I think `__construct` function will called only when the new object instance if created . so you need to create instance to run the constructor function .

```
class Get_category_type {

 function __construct()
 {
   if (isset($_POST['category_name']) && !empty($_POST['category_name'])) {
       global $wpdb;
       $category = $_POST['category_name'];
       $ps_type_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'ps_type';
       $types = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT type FROM ' . 
       $ps_type_table_name . ' WHERE category=%s', $category));

      foreach ($types as $type) 
      {
         $result.= '<option value="' . $type . '">' . $type . '</option>';
      }
      echo  $result;
   }
 }

}

 $obj = new Get_category_type(); //create instance here .
```

**2nd :** Don't echo inside foreach just echo after foreach like this

```
foreach ($types as $type) 
{
   $result.= '<option value="' . $type . '">' . $type . '</option>';
}
echo  $result;
```

**3rd :**  you need to append the option like this

```
  $('#type').empty();
  $('#type').append(html);
```

**4th :** The data should be sent proper way in ajax

```
    data:{category_name:category},
```

**5th :**  Add error handler in ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'category-type-select.php',
    data:{category_name=category},
    success:function (html) {
         $('#type').empty();
         $('#type').append(html);
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
});
```

**Testing purpose :**

For testing purpose .change your POST method to GET method like this `if (isset($_GET['category_name']) && !empty($_GET['category_name'])) { .. }`  Then call the url directly in browser like this . `http://yoursite.com/category-type-select.php?category_name=here_any_one_category_name` . if it's  run then porblem is in your ajax part .

Comment: its not working bro , i think i have to path to call PHP file inside WordPress, like:plugin_dir_path(FILE)/category-type-select.php, I don't know currect way of writing it –

Comment: press F12 to open the developer tool and navigate the console . and change something on you select box . now you can see any log if it is exists . @DeekshithShetty

Comment: for testing purpose .change your POST method to get method like this if (isset($_GET['category_name']) && !empty($_GET['category_name'])) { .. }  Then call the url directly in browser like this . http://yoursite.com/category-type-select.php?category_name=here_any_one_category_name . if it's is run then porblem is in your ajax part . @DeekshithShetty

Comment: take look on my answer and follow all the steps to get succeed @DeekshithShetty

Comment: it is wordpress file , can i run it , giving direct path?

Comment: in current url in browser just replcae the file name with this file name like this yoursite.com/category-type-select.php?category_name=here_any_one_category_name

Comment: http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=image-selector this is my current path and http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/category-type-select.php?categoy_name=category-1 this is i replaces , but it showing page not found

Comment: and i did console as u said, there not showing any ajax script